# PowerPoint advance to any slide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

On Microsoft PowerPoint, is it possible to change slides automatically, not to the next slide but to one completely new for example slide 2 to slide 7 without clicking anything at all?

Please respond

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/504061/74620 You might also be interested in the answer http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/advance-another-slide-number-not-next-slide-t3867767.html where it's stated that 'You need to make each of the reference slides a custom show.

When you link choose "Custom show" and tick show and return. When the user
clicks for the next slide in the custom show they will return to the slide
with the hyperlink.'

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version of PowerPoint you are using, but depending on what your goals are for the presentation I would say you could change the animation times so that they zoom through the slides you want to skip. Also you could use a macro. I found this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172148%28v=office.11%29.aspx that includes macros to force go to slide #n.

Example:

```
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
    .GotoSlide 3, msoFalse
End With
```

Comment: That would require clicking something to get the macro to run.  Joseph mentioned that he wants the slide change to happen w/o clicking.